# Recommended layout for component that always stays in the same place on the x-axis?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

My situation is a bit complex, so rather than explain I'll just show a picture of what I currently have:

[image: Screenshot of the UI]

The idea is that I want to move the instrument selector (the combo box that says "Flute" in each staff) above the staff.  However, I always want to keep it in the same place, on the left directly above the staff, even when scrolling horizontally.  When scrolling vertically, it should move so that it is always directly above its staff.  Kind of like a toolbar.  The problem is that it's already inside of a JScrollPane (as there could be multiple staves and you need to scroll both axes and there's one "instrument panel" per staff (though eventually there will be other UI elements to interact with in this pseudo-toolbar local to to staff in which it is attached)).  Is this something where using absolute positioning + listening for scroll/resize/window move events is needed?  Or is there perhaps a layout I'm not aware of that can do this sort of thing?

Thanks for looking!

Comment: This isn't solid, hence comment instead of answer, but I'd shift the ComboBox to it's own panel above the panel that contains the staff. That way you can keep the ComboBox panel static while having the ScrollPane beneath it.

Comment: @Gorb Unfortunately, that would mean that each staff would need its own horizontal scrolling and they could be scrolled to different positions, rather than having a single horizontal scroll bar at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add the components to individual scroll panes, but never show the horizontal scrollbar
2. Have all the scroll panes share the same BoundRangeModel.
3. Create a separate JScrollBar component that uses this model. Whenever its scrolls the separate scroll panes will also scroll:

Something like:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class ScrollSSCCE extends JPanel
{
    public ScrollSSCCE()
    {
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        BoundedRangeModel model = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Flute " + i);
            label.setAlignmentX(JComponent.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
            add( label );

            JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(3, 20);
            textArea.setText("Just some text to make a horizontal scroll necessary");
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textArea );
            scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
            scrollPane.setAlignmentX(JComponent.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
            add( scrollPane );

            //  Share the horizontal scrollbar model

            JScrollBar horizontal = scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar();

            if (i == 0)
                model = horizontal.getModel();
            else
                horizontal.setModel( model );
        }

        //  Create the scrollbar that uses the shared model

        JScrollBar shared = new JScrollBar( JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL );
        shared.setModel( model );
        shared.setAlignmentX(JComponent.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        add( shared );
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Scroll SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new ScrollSSCCE() );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setSize(200, 400);
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Edit:

You can actually do this without even creating the "shared" scrollbar. Just use the scrollbar of the last scrollpane:

```
if (i != 4)
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

> I need a vertical scroll bar as well.

Don't think you need to create another panel. Just add the current panel directly to a scroll pane:

```
JScrollPane master = new JScrollPane( new ScrollSSCCE() );
master.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Scroll SSCCE");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
//frame.add( new ScrollSSCCE() );
frame.add( master );
frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
frame.setSize(200, 400);
frame.setVisible( true );
```

That's the last tip I have. I won't be around for a couple of days. Good luck.

Comment: I very much like this answer, but it unfortunately falls short of my requirements by a hair. I need to be able to vertically scroll through all staves, so I need a vertical scroll bar as well. I played with your example by putting everything in a master scrollpane and set that horizontal scroll bar to use the same model as the others, and while I now have vertical scroll the horizontal scrolling is incorrect (ui "wiggles", scroll bar changes size, and the flute label moves). Perhaps I missed something? Could you take a quick look at my modifications: http://pastebin.com/42k4jSJR ?

Comment: @user450775, made an edit which may or may not help.

Comment: Your edit for vertical scrolling worked! There's two minor issues: scrolling with the wheel doesn't work when the mouse is over a staff (which I may be able to work around by capturing scroll events and forwarding them to the master scroll pane) and the horizontal scroll bar may not always be visible (if you've scrolled up) - but I think I can get around that by putting it in an OverlayLayout or a LayeredPane.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I got this working to some extend with the following approach:

- Put a JPanel with null Layout over the staff
- Add the comboBox to this panel
- Make the panel height the same as the comboBox and as width as the staff (as width as you can scroll)
- Add an `AdjusmentListener` to the horizontal bar to update the coordinate X of the comboBoxes.

In other words the comboBoxes slides inside their null layout panels to match the position you are looking at. It is not perfect because this causes the comboBoxes to wiggle a little when you are moving the scrollBar.

The mock interface that I made looking like yours is the following:

[image: screenshot]

Notice how in the screenshot the horizontal bar is moved but the comboBoxes with "Flute" are still visible.

So the most important code is:

- Put the comboBox inside a null layout panel:

  ```
  JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(new String[]{"Flute", "Piano", "Cello"});
  comboBox.setBounds(0, 0, comboBox.getPreferredSize().width, comboBox.getPreferredSize().height);
  _comboBoxes.add(comboBox);

  JPanel comboBoxPanel = new JPanel();
  comboBoxPanel.setLayout(null);
  comboBoxPanel.add(comboBox);
  ```

  Then you put this panel over the staff, with whatever layout you are using. In my case I had a Panel with a vertical Box Layout containg the comboBoxPanel and the red panel where the staff would be.
- Add a listener to the scroll bar and update the comboBoxes position inside their panels:

  ```
  scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {
      @Override
      public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e)
      {
          for (JComboBox comboBox : _comboBoxes)
          {
              comboBox.setLocation(e.getValue(), 0);
          }
      }
  });
  ```

Full code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentEvent;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class ScrollIndependentTest
{
    private ArrayList<JComboBox> _comboBoxes = new ArrayList<JComboBox>();

    public static final void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {
                new ScrollIndependentTest().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setTitle("Fourier Synthesis");

        JPanel listPanel = new JPanel();
        listPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(listPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            listPanel.add(createStaffPanel());
        }

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(listPanel);
        scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e)
            {
                for(JComboBox comboBox : _comboBoxes)
                {
                    //if (comboBox.isVisible()) //maybe?
                    comboBox.setLocation(e.getValue(), 0);
                }
            }
        });
        frame.add(scrollPane);

        /*
         * Cosmetic elements to make it look more similar to your case
         */
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.add(new JMenu("File"));
        menuBar.add(new JMenu("Synthesis"));
        menuBar.add(new JMenu("Help"));
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        JPanel toolBar = new JPanel();
        toolBar.setLayout(new BoxLayout(toolBar, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            toolBar.add(new JButton("Note " + i));
        }
        frame.add(toolBar, BorderLayout.WEST);
        /*
         *  end
         */

        frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createStaffPanel()
    {
        JPanel staffPanel = new JPanel();
        staffPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(staffPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        staffPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(new String[]{"Flute", "Piano", "Cello"});
        comboBox.setBounds(0, 0, comboBox.getPreferredSize().width, comboBox.getPreferredSize().height);
        _comboBoxes.add(comboBox);

        JPanel comboBoxPanel = new JPanel();
        comboBoxPanel.setLayout(null);
        comboBoxPanel.add(comboBox);

        comboBoxPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, comboBox.getPreferredSize().height));
        staffPanel.add(comboBoxPanel);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.red);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 100));
        panel.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        staffPanel.add(panel);

        return staffPanel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this!  I wonder if there's a way to remove the "wobbling" of the UI components?  Other than that, this fits my requirements perfectly.  I tried it out and the wobbling is pretty obvious.